# Inter-Communication (Directive to Service to Controller)

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a multiple file upload module and am stuck when it comes to communicating from my service to my controller without using `$rootScope`.

A directive watches the file input and hands the files `onchange` to a service, where they get uploaded and the upload progress monitored. Based on the response (from success, error and progress changes), the parent controller should show thumbs and progress.

I do not want to use `$emit` and `$on` on my `$rootScope`, since I need the pattern quiet often and only that one parent controller needs to know about the uploads.

I created a simplified(!) **[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/46ERnMyb7n2LBzqTn9IM?p=preview)** with some additional information to better understand the problem.

Is there another way for my controller to react to changes (happening inside the service factory)?
Or maybe a completely different way of achieving such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper way to handle async operations with Angular is using [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q).

You could return a promise from the service call and resolve it to the `src` of the thumb. You could then not use a directive at all.

Your controller would use the service this way:

```js
function ParentController($scope, imageService) {
  $scope.change = function() {
    $scope.src = imageService.change();

    $scope.then(function(result) {
      // the loading ended, but there is no need to set the src
      // as it will already bind to src when ends. 
    }, function(err) {
      // something went wrong
    });
  };
 }
```

Your service:

```js
app.factory('imageService', function($q, $rootScope) {

  function doTheUploading(defer) {
    if (everythingOk) {
      defer.resolve(thumbSrcString); 
    } else {
      defer.reject({something: 'an error ocurred'});
    }
  }

  return {
    change: function() {
      // creates the promise
      var defer = $q.defer();
      doSomethingAsync(defer);
      return defer.promise;
    }
  };

});
```

At least, your HTML should look like:

```html
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <img src="{{ src }}"><br><br>
  <span class="btn" ng-click="change()">Change!</span>
</div>
```

Regarding the progress, you will need to go with callbacks or returning an object that would bring the promise and a progress indicator (i.e: `return {promise: defer.promise, percent: 0}`). The progress indicator should be then updated from inside the service.

You could also chain your promise if you need any transformation in the URL returned from the server before sets it to the `src` property, i.e.:

```js
$scope.src = imageService.change().then(function(result) {
    return 'http://dummyimage.com/' + result;
  });
```

Updated [your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bs6WDGzZCzE7fJA7wJCC?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very detailed answer :) I looked into the promise API but I have one question regarding the progress: I would return the promise and progress only after it is either resolved or rejected, right? That means the progress is either 100 or 0 as well. But `onprogress` is a continuous event. And when I have to use `$emit` for the progress, wouldn't it make sense to use events for everything?

Comment: The returning object idea is quite unusual, indeed. Another solution (I'd rather prefer) would be using callbacks. Passing a callback to the service (`imageService.change(this.handleOnProgress)`) and keep calling it to advise on progress from inside the service. I'm currently implementing [`promise.progress`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#progress-notification) in Angular promises, but I don't know yet if it will be accepted/approved, and if it get approved, we don't know when it would ship anyway, so if you need it in time, better go with callback.

Comment: Hi @JohnB. The [promise notification PR has been merged](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2223). If you use the unstable version or you compile the code yourself, you can expect this feature for the next releases.

Comment: Happy to see it merged. Thanks for letting me know!